# Opening a .html with window.location

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm writing a simple login page in Ajax + Jquery
I have an error when I click on the button. And I don't understand why.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

At this line
`echo '<input type="button" value="connexion" OnClick="window.location.assign("http://localhost/loginmap/members/success.html")>';`

There is my code

```
<?php 
session_start();
//si le user a un session de ouverte
    /*if(isset($_SESSION['connecté'])){
        header('Location : success.html');
        die();
    }*/
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','','monumap');

        $email = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['emailPHP']); 
        $password = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['passwordPHP']); 

        $data = $connection->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'"); 
        if($data->num_rows >= 0) {//tout et ok -> connexion
            $_SESSION['connecté'] = '1';
            //$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            header('Location:'.$_SESSION['redirectURL']);
            exit('<font color = "green">Connexion reussi...</font>');
        }else{
            exit('<font color = "red">Le Mot de passe / Email est inconnue </font>');
        }
    
        //exit($email . " = " . $password);
    } 
?> 


<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Monumap Connexion</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form method="post" action="login.php">
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email..."><br> 
            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Mot de passe..."><br> 
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="login"> 
        </form> 
    
        <p id = "reponse"></p>

        <div class="Bouton">
            <?php if($_SESSION['connecté']==1){
                
                echo '<input type="button" value="connexion" OnClick="window.location.assign("http://localhost/loginmap/members/success.html")>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#login").on('click', function () { 
                    var email = $("#email").val(); 
                    var password = $("#password").val(); 

                    if (email == "" || password == "") 
                        alert('vos inputs sont vides'); 
                    
                    else { 
                        $.ajax(
                            {
                                url: 'login.php',
                                method: 'POST', 
                                data: { 
                                    login: 1, 
                                    emailPHP: email, 
                                    passwordPHP: password 
                                },
                                success: function (reponse) {
                                    $("#reponse").html(reponse);
                                },
                                    dataType: 'text'
                            }
                        );
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take good care of opening and closing quotes. You never end your `onclick`. And use escaped single quotes around the url

Comment: Oh i see 

`echo '<input type="button" value="connexion" OnClick="window.location.assign('http://localhost/loginmap/members/success.html')">';`

I write this  but i still got the same error at the same line
@brombeer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<input type="button" value="connexion" onclick="window.location.assign('."'http://localhost/loginmap/members/success.html'".');")/>';
```

It's cause you wrote quote character.

You can use this way as well.

```
echo '<input type="button" value="connexion" onclick="func()"/>';
?>

<script>
    function func(){
        window.location.assign("http://localhost/loginmap/members/success.html");
    }
</script>
```